# Retain encoding within SimpleXML

Tags: php, encoding, simplexml

I am loading an XML file into SimpleXML. The SimpleXML file is then processed into a different XML layout and written to disk.

The original XML file has attributes such as `&amp; &lt; &gt;` within attribute values and element values. When imported into SimpleXML these are changed to & < >. I need to retain the original encoding when output into the new XML layout.

Is there a way of stopping SimpleXML from changing these values or of easily resetting them after the import.

Example original XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Players> 
   <Player id="12134" first_name="Dave" last_name="O&#39;Shea" />    
</Players>
```

SimpleXML

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Player] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 12134
                    [first_name] => Dave
                    [last_name] => O'Shea
                )

        )

)
```

Example Output Needed

```
<xu:List> 
   <xu:Item id="5687" name="Dave O&#39;Shea" />    
</xu:List>
```

I need to retain the value of O &# 39; Shea instead of O'Shea. I do not have control over the original XML. This is just an example the actual XML file is much bigger and i would need to apply this to any attribute or value.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleXml cannot produce invalid XML, so any attributes with encoded entitites cannot be transformed after import. Consider this testcase:

```
$xml = <<< XML
<root>
    <element attr="3 &amp; 5 are &lt; 9 but &gt; 6"/>
</root>
XML;
$root = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $root->asXml();
```

The above will give:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <element attr="3 &amp; 5 are &lt; 9 but &gt; 6"/>
</root>
```

As you can see, the attributes are still encoded. It is only when you pull them out with

```
$attr = $root->element['attr'];
echo $attr;
```

that they are unencoded to `3 & 5 are < 9 but > 6`. If you dont want that, run the string through [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to re-encode the entities. But since SimpleXml cannot produce invalid XML, you dont have to reencode them when putting them anywhere in the XML that requires them to be encoded, e.g.

```
$root->element[]['attr'] = $attr; // create new element with attribute
$root->element[1] = $attr;        // add attribute as element node value
echo $root->asXml();
```

will result in (manually formatted for readability)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <element attr="3 &amp; 5 are &lt; 9 but &gt; 6"/>
    <element attr="3 &amp; 5 are &lt; 9 but &gt; 6">
        3 &amp; 5 are &lt; 9 but &gt; 6
    </element>
</root>
```

So there shouldn't be any issues. In fact, when trying to put htmlencoded entities back into XML, those will get messed up, because entities start with an ampersand and that would get encoded then to, for instance, &lt;, resulting in a string like

```
&amp;amp; 5 are &amp;lt; 9 but &amp;gt; 6
```

#### Edit after update

Note SimpleXml will only automatically handle &, >, < and " because those are defined entitites for XML. The character encodings you show are not. Consequently, when using UTF-8, there should be no need to have them as character encodings, because the XML will still be valid. If your consuming code requires those entities, I'd suggest to handle conversion in the consuming code and not force them into the XML.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was trying to achieve what wasn't possible. I have changed my consuming code to replace the encoding at output.

Comment: @Matt well, it might be possible with a DTD and DOM or something but I'm not sure and I dont think it would be worth the effort anyways. Any application in 2011 should be able to handle UTF-8.